# Regarding python dictionary function

Tags: python

I coded the following stuff to print out dictionary `('one' : 1, 'tow' : 2, 'three' : 3)`. but errors come out. Can anyone answer why ti that so?

```
length = []

class_one = [1, 2, 3]

class_two = ['one', 'two', 'three']

for x in class_one:

    if x < 4:

        length[class_two] = class_one

print(length)
```

Comment: Basically `dict(zip(class_two, class_one))`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary This doesn't take into account the conditional though

Answer (score 2):

```
length = {}

class_one = [1, 2, 3]

class_two = ['one', 'two', 'three']

for c1, c2 in zip(class_one, class_two):
    if c1 < 4:

        length[c2] = c1

print(length)
```

Here, this gives you the desired output. Basically, you were iterating over `class_one`, then trying to use the entirety of `class_two` as a key for `length`. Here, you iterate over both arrays and use the values as keys

Comment: @Brick oh ye, thats because you can't use a list as key. can you describe what the code is trying to do?

Comment: Change `length[class_two] = class_one` to `length[class_two] = x`

Comment: @ikkuh that still won't work, the issue is using a list as a key

Comment: @Ashwini's comment in the questions is the best way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the corrected version of your code:

```
length = {}
class_one = [1, 2, 3]    
class_two = ['one', 'two', 'three']

for i, x in enumerate(class_two):
    length[x] = class_one[i]    
print(length)
```

The problems with your version were:

- the initializing the `length dict` (you used `[]` which is for `list`s; use `{}` instead.)
- assigning the values to the `dict`: using the whole `list` as `key` which is wrong since `list`s are not hashable and not what you want to do anyway.

---

or simply and much more elegantly:

```
length = dict(zip(class_two, class_one))
```

which is the **best way to do it** in your case (disregarding the conditional).

they both `print`: `{'one' : 1, 'two' : 2, 'three' : 3}`

---

Finally, you can have the *dict comprehension* version which goes like this:

```
length = {k: v for k, v in zip(class_two, class_one)}
```

among other variations one can think of. Note that this is an **overkill for your case**.

---

> The conditional

As far as the conditional goes `if x < 4:` not sure why you have that there since with the present example inputs provided it does not make sense but if you do need it, it is easy to re-implement.

As an example of how that would look like take a look at the following:

```
length = {k: class_one[i] for i, k in enumerate(class_two) if class_one[i] < 4}
```

or the shorter:

```
length = {class_two[i]: v for i, v in enumerate(class_one) if v < 4}
```

or the fancier (and even shorter):

```
length = {k: v for k, v in zip(class_two, class_one) if v < 4}
```

Comment: you should add the conditional in the dict comprehension to show a full case. Maybe the example was just a silly one to make the point and not the intended final use case.

Comment: Down vote? No idea why. But I feel this is good solution though and good explanation. 
My solution is almost same. 
`>>> {x:i for i,x in zip(class_one,class_two)}
{'three': 3, 'two': 2, 'one': 1}`

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel Sure thing.